# « Ça n'a pas » ou « ça n'est pas » ?

Tags: syntaxe, constructions

Que dit-on ?

> Le paiement n'a pas passé

> Le paiement n'est pas passé

Existe-t-il une différence et comment sait-on ce qu'il faudrait mettre ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La différence tient à l’auxiliaire employé, le verbe avoir ou être.

- avoir

  S'utilise quand il y a un lien d'appartenance entre le sujet et le complément. Exemples :

  - au présent (verbe) :

    > Le chat n'*a* pas de puces.
  - au passé composé (auxiliaire) :

    > Le chat *a* grossi.
  - Il n'est pas possible de faire une phrase au présent avec le verbe avoir synonyme a l'exemple.

  Ici on lie les puces ou le poids au chat, ce sont des caractéristiques de l'animal.
- être

  S'utilise dans une description d'état, de fait ou d'attitude. Exemples :

  - Au présent (verbe) :

    > Le chat n'*est* pas couvert de puces.
  - Au passé composé (auxiliaire) :

    > Le chat *est* devenu gros.
  - En passant l'exemple de la question au présent dans un sens synonyme :

    > Le paiement *est* valide

  Dans ce cas on décrit l'état du chat et on ne lie plus les puces ou le poids au chat.

Ici c'est donc bien "Le paiement n'est pas passé", la phrase décrit l'état du paiement.

Personnellement pour savoir quel auxiliaire employé je me base sur sur cette distinction, avoir si il y a possibilité d'un lien d'appartenance et être si c'est un état.

Plus de détails [ici](http://www.espacefrancais.com/les-verbes-auxiliaires-etre-et-avoir/) sur les auxiliaires.

Pour les règles d'utilisation des auxiliaires de façon générales voir [ici](http://grammaire.reverso.net/1_1_15_Avoir_ou_etre_aux_temps_composes.shtml), le verbe "passer" est un cas particulier dans la mesure où il a une forme [transitive et intransitive](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/passer) suivant le sens qu'on lui donne et qu'il peut prendre un sens de mouvement amenant l'utilisation de l'auxiliaire être.  Je cite le lien:

> Tous les verbes transitifs non pronominaux se conjuguent avec avoir.
>   [...]
>   En plus des verbes pronominaux, un certain nombre de verbes
>   intransitifs qui expriment un mouvement ou un changement d'état se
>   conjuguent avec l'auxiliaire être.

Quelques exemple spécifique au verbe passer :

- > Elle est passé par la porte principale
- > Minuit est passé sans que la cloche sonne

Dans le second le sens de mouvement est induit implicitement par le mouvement de l'aiguille passant devant le 12 de l'horloge, le verbe est intransitif.

- > Il a passé son examen d'entrée

"son examen" se réfère au sujet et on retrouve la notion d'appartenance, le verbe passer est transitif.

- > Il a passé ses notes de cours à son ami
- > Il a passé le sel et le poivre à son voisin de table

Ici "passer" a le sens de "prêter" ou "donner", on retrouve la notion d'appartenance même si le complément n'appartient pas au sens propre au sujet, c'est bien le sujet qui a le complément en main. On pourrait imaginer un sens de mouvement dans le dernier cas comme pour l'horloge mais je pense que seule les expression d'heure ou de durée utilisent l'auxiliaire "être". le verbe est transitif également ici.

L'application des règles générales est un peu complexes avec "passer", c'est pourquoi je préfère me référer à cette aide "état ou appartenance" pour expliquer le choix a faire. Je n'ai pas trouver d'exemple invalidant cette méthode mais je ne peux pas garantir qu'il n'en existe aucun.

Comment: Quoi? Est-ce que c'est une blague? Je pense, *passer* est un verbe, donc la question est, est-ce qu'on fait le passé composé avec *être* ou avec *avoir*? Il y a des règles pour ca, mais ces règles n'ont rien à faire avec appartenance ou ètat. Je suis sorti. J'ai achêté. Nous sommes allez. Vous avez oubliés. Non?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann "Tous les verbes transitifs non pronominaux se conjuguent avec avoir.", "Tous les verbes pronominaux se conjuguent avec être." et "un certain nombre de verbes intransitifs qui expriment un mouvement ou un changement d'état se conjuguent avec l'auxiliaire être.". Manque de chance, `passer` a une forme transitive et intransitive, de plus il peut être pris pour un verbe de déplacement. Je ne pense pas que ça aide dans ce cas. (Au passage aucun de vos exemples n'infirme ma méthode 'simplifiée' qui n'a pas d'autre prétention que d'être une aide).

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Si vous voyez une façon limpide d'exposer ces règles au cas de la question je ne saurais que vous encourager à écrire une réponse.

Comment: Mersi bien pour répondre si vitement et détaillément. Èvidement je n'avait pas compris que votre premier réponse est basé sur la règle fondamentale pour composer le passé composé. - Je pense qu'il me faut du temps pour digester les détails. (Je ne suis pas très chèvronné au francais. Pardon.)

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann pas de soucis, je ne voyais pas de façon simple de répondre en citant les règle d'utilisation des auxiliaire pour ce cas, c'est pour ça que j'ai préféré une méthode alternative :)

Comment: @Christian Les verbes variables posent en effet beaucoup de problèmes pour tout apprenant, je trouve avec mes élèves privés. On réussit enfin à distinguer (1) une liste célèbre qui comprend "aller", "venir", etc. (2) les verbes pronominaux (3) tout autre verbe utilise "avoir"... Puis on rencontre une phrase comme a citée l'OP et la "maison de cartes" tombe !

Comment: Je suis loin d'être aussi versé dans la technique du français que vous, mais l'emploi d'exemples au présent pour illustrer le choix d'un auxiliaire me paraît au mieux propice à la confusion...

Comment: @LaurentS. Effectivement, j'ai revu la formulation de la réponse.

Comment: @LukeSawczak *la maison de carte tombe* → *le château de cartes s'écroule*